# How to remove the last element of a list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have created a list in **C** using a self-referential structure, I figured how to do every thing possible with the list but delete the last element, this is puzzling me for a few weeks now, please help me 
this is what I did.
To get the concept of this program you only have to look at functions `main`,and  `Delete`, maybe  `insert`. Please note that tis code was compiled on linux using gcc in ubuntu.

```
/* self-referencial structure */
struct ListNode
{
    char data;
struct ListNode *nextNode ;
};


typedef struct ListNode ListNode;
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr ;

/* function protypes */
void insert(ListNodePtr *sptr, char value); // insert element in list in alphabet order
void Delete (ListNodePtr *sptr);// PROBLEM HERE; remove last element from list
void printList(ListNodePtr);// output the contents of the list
void instructions(); // print instruction on screen

int main(void)
{
ListNodePtr startPtr = NULL ; // there are initially no nodes
int choice;
char item ;// char to be placed in list

/* Give instruction s and allow user to make a choice
 * insert , print, delete.
 */
instructions();
printf("?");
scanf("%d", &choice);

/* loop until sentinel value 3 */
while (!(choice == 4) )
{
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Enter a character");
        scanf("\n%c",&item);
        insert(&startPtr, item);
        printList(startPtr);
        break ;

    case 2:
        /* If the list is not empty */
        Delete(&startPtr);
        printList(startPtr);
        // if it is printf("the list is empty");
        break;
    case 3:
        printList(startPtr);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid choice");
        break;
    }// end switch
    printf("?");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
}// end while
return 0 ;
}// END FUNCTION MAIN

/* display program choices/instruction to user */
void instructions(void)
{
     printf( "Enter your choice:\n"
    "1 to insert an element into the list.\n"
    "2 to delete an element from the list.\n"
    "3 to print the list\n"
    "4 to end.\n" );
 }

void insert(ListNodePtr *sptr, char value)
{
ListNodePtr currentPtr;
ListNodePtr previousPtr;
ListNodePtr newNode ;


/* create an area in memory the size of ListNode and
 *allocate to newPtr */
newNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); // create new node

// if space is available
if (newNode != NULL)
{
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->nextNode = NULL;

    previousPtr = NULL ;
    currentPtr = *sptr ;

    /* walk to correct location in the list */
    while (currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data)
    {
        previousPtr = currentPtr;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextNode;
    }// end while

    /* insert node at beginning of the list */
    if(previousPtr == NULL)
    {
        newNode->nextNode = *sptr;
        *sptr = newNode;
    }// end if

    else
    {
        previousPtr->nextNode = newNode;
        newNode->nextNode = currentPtr ;
    }
}// end if
else
{
    printf("%c not inserted , memory not available", value);
}

 }

void Delete(ListNodePtr *sptr)
{
ListNodePtr previousPtr;
ListNodePtr currentPtr;
ListNodePtr tempPtr;

// if there is only  one element
if((*sptr)->nextNode == NULL)
{
    tempPtr = *sptr; // hold on to Node being removed
    *sptr = (*sptr)->nextNode;
    free(tempPtr);
}
else
{
    previousPtr = *sptr ;
    currentPtr = (*sptr)->nextNode;

    // walk to end of the list
    while(currentPtr->nextNode != NULL)
    {
        previousPtr = *sptr;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextNode;
    }

    if(currentPtr != NULL)
    {
        // WHAT DO I DO HERE ??!!??
        // if the list has more than one two elements, 
        // all but the first element is deleted

        previousPtr->nextNode = currentPtr->nextNode;
        currentPtr = NULL ;
        free(currentPtr);
    }// end if
}// end else 


 }// END FUNCTION DELETE

 void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr)
{
if(currentPtr == NULL)
printf("List is empty");
else
{
    while(currentPtr != NULL)
    {
        printf( "%c --> ", currentPtr->data );
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextNode;
    } /* end while */
        printf( "NULL\n\n" );
    /* end else */


}
}
```

Comment: Think about the concept of what it means to not have a next element and how this affects your perception of last. After you figure that out you should have no problem in figuring out how to remove the last element.

Comment: i understand that the last element has to point to NULL, and that to remove the last element you remove the element between NULL and the node before the on you are trying to remove. but i don't know if i am implementing the code incorrectly, but i just cant get it.

Comment: You don't actually have to navigate to the last node to find out if it's followed by a `NULL` node.

Comment: using a sentry node and a doubly linked list makes life simpler. see [here](http://pastebin.com/HC1DLK4M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this helps

```
void Delete(ListNodePtr *sptr)
{
 ListNodePtr previousPtr;
 ListNodePtr currentPtr; 
 ListNodePtr tempPtr;

 if((*sptr)->nextNode == NULL)
 {
   tempPtr = *sptr; // hold on to Node being removed
   *sptr = (*sptr)->nextNode;
   free(tempPtr);
 }
else  
{
previousPtr = *sptr ;
currentPtr = (*sptr)->nextNode;

// walk to end of the list
while(currentPtr->nextNode != NULL)
{
    previousPtr=previousPtr->nextNode;//this always points to the previous node 
    currentPtr = currentPtr->nextNode;
}

//after loop ends currentPtr points to the last node

if(currentPtr != NULL)
{
    previousPtr->nextNode=NULL;//This deletes the currentPtr from the list
    free(currentPtr);
}// end if
}// end else 
}// END FUNCTION DELETE
```

Comment: thank you. Another way i found it could be done is by moving to the second to last element(not the last), assign previousPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; and then free currentPtr.